# Zero system navigation insets in Jetpack Compose for Android API < 30

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a fragment in which I set ComposeView. I'm checking the system navigation insets for the root view and for the Compose like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            val compatWindowInsets = WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(view?.rootWindowInsets!!, view)
            val systemInsetTypesMask = WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars()
            val viewSystemInsets = compatWindowInsets.getInsets(systemInsetTypesMask)
            println("---> View: ${viewSystemInsets.bottom}")
        
            val composeSystemInsets = WindowInsets.navigationBars
            println("---> Compose: ${composeSystemInsets.getBottom(LocalDensity.current)}")

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And for Android API >= 30 I get next result:

```
---> View: 126
---> Compose: 126
```

But for Android API < 30 I get:

```
---> View: 126
---> Compose: 0
```

For Compose it's always zero, what is causing this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code on devices with API levels 27 & 33 and I've got 0 as the bottom `navigationBars` insets on both.

It turns out that after enabling [Edge-To-Edge](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge) in the Activity `onCreate` function, the compose insets are working fine on both devices.

Here is a detailed documentation of [Window insets in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets).

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Enable Edge-To-Edge in [androidx.activity] version >= 1.8
    enableEdgeToEdge()

    // Enable Edge-To-Edge in [androidx.activity] version < 1.8
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    /// ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`
is already active in app, without this, the insets would not even apply to the view.